# Seth-rpc error "Alias not found in key directory" even though alias created in seth-cli-go

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to unlock my created alias(created using seth-cli-go) in seth-rpc container. I am using the following command in seth-rpc:

```
docker exec -it seth-rpc bash
seth-rpc --connect tcp://validator:4004 --bind 0.0.0.0:3030 --unlock myalias
```

On running the above command, I am getting the following error:
'Alias not found in key directory'

Account creation in seth-cli-go:

```
docker exec -it seth-cli-go bash
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -out key-file.pem -aes128
seth account import key-file.pem myalias
seth account create --nonce=0 --wait myalias
Account created
Transaction Receipt:  {
  "TransactionID": "bfc03a624baf4ac0f7c983057ae8ce7306190f47029f891e92f8b268b6009b9a3982d0c56dc9ebc45f40d9dc058bb36c76e816398f1046ac95ce48b9bc546aab",
  "Address": "29b71fd0c3100d9595cd9daefa9850e16feb2831"
}
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for the problem.
In the docker-compose.yaml file, add "- sawtooth:/root/.sawtooth" under the "volumes" section of seth-cli-go. This makes sure that the aliases created under the seth-cli-go docker container is visible to seth-rpc container as well. 
We can unlock the alias from seth-rpc with this.
But, after unlock if I am trying to send a transaction using "eth_sendTransaction", it shows an internal error: "Account with address  not found".

```
$ seth-rpc --unlock myalias --connect tcp://validator:4004 --bind 0.0.0.0:3030
02c0b4c855d0e54a7f6dc5635e2aab0714387ba88b678fe2cc264ce0917fab83b6 unlocked: 373ec8d9b7d1814aa4d081ab4241bf618d73f384

$ curl -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_sendTransaction", "id": 2, "params": [{"from": "0x373ec8d9b7d1814aa4d081ab4241bf618d73f384", "data": "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"}]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:3030
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603,"message":"Internal error"},"id":2}
```

Another thing is no error message is getting logged in the terminal where I am binding the validator(port 4004) with seth-rpc(port 3030). But, error is getting logged in the sawtooth validator terminal.
Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: The error is logged in the validator because it is the validator that does the lookup and does not find the object in the global state.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the Sawtooth Seth source code with PR#49
https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-seth/pull/49/files
Integrated 2018-07-10.
So recent versions of Seth should not have this problem.